# cocos2d enable touch in second scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, layer, scene

i have menu with buttons
when touch the Play button 
game go to another scene
but Touch don't work there
i'm write
self.isToucheEnabled=YES;
in init method
and add in onEnter method
         [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] setDispatchEvents:YES];

but that don't work
pleas help why i can enable touch

Comment: Provide your code. And ask your question specifically. Is your menu button not working or Your layer not responding to touch??

Comment: my layer not responding to touch

Answer (score 2):

You must put the following code:

`-(void) onEnter { 
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}`

inside the scene you want to enable the TouchDispatcher on, then in the same scene make sure you enter this:

`-(void) onExit {
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
}`

and the touch should register in every scene that you have the above code in.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you define a menu in cocos2d ([source](http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle)):

```
CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage  temFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.jpg" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(starButtonTapped:)];
starMenuItem.position = ccp(60, 60);
CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
[self addChild:starMenu];
```

If you need more help, please provide the code that you are using to create the menu.

Comment: - (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 NSLog(@"touch");
 return YES;
}
i have this method but that dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate interface in your CCLayer in your header!

e.g.:

```
@interface YourScene : CCLayer <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>  {
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the layer use:

-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Not:

-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event